# How can I use Voice Recognition to open intents, like email and text messaging?

Tags: android

Hi how can I use the Voice Recognition to open intents, like email and text?  I would like to use the sample code provided by android but this code only returns a list of phrases it thought it heard.  Where can I change the code to open up an email intent when user voices "send email".  From what I understand I can implement predetermined phrases for the listener to listen for.  Can anyone  show me in the code below where and how this is done?

```
/**
 * Sample code that invokes the speech recognition intent API.
 */
public class VoiceRecognition extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private static final int VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE = 1234;

    private ListView mList;

    /**
     * Called with the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
        setContentView(R.layout.voice_recognition);

        // Get display items for later interaction
        Button speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_speak);

        mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
                new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
        if (activities.size() != 0) {
            speakButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        } else {
            speakButton.setEnabled(false);
            speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handle the click on the start recognition button.
     */
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btn_speak) {
            startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Fire an intent to start the speech recognition activity.
     */
    private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    /**
     * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    matches));
        }

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

}

Comment: See my answere http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122400/android-voice-recognition-commands/23931056#23931056

Answer (score 1):

```
public Interface Detector{
    public boolean detect(List<String> matches);
}

public class OnStrictEmailListener implements Detector{

    public boolean detect(List<String> matches){
        if (matches.contains("send") 
            ||  matches.contains("email")
            || matches.contains("send email")){
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }

}

public class OnWeakEmailListener implements Detector{

    public boolean detect(List<String> matches){
        for (String match: matches){
                   if (match.contains("send")
                   || match.contains("email")) return true
                return false;
    }

}


/**
 * Handle the results from the recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
        ArrayList<String> YourMatchesToCheck = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);

        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                YourMatchesToCheck));

    }
    //Detector d = new OnStrictEmailListener();
    Detector d = new OnWeakEmailListener();
    if(d.detect(YourMatchesToCheck){
        //....
    } else {
        //...
    } 

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

there you can start Intents check for other stuff etc

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following code. Simply call the `getVoice()` method when you want to listen for voice input, then have that automatically call `searchVoiceArray()` as my code does which will match the possible reponses google provides with what your looking for.

```
public void getvoice() {
                        Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                        i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH, RecognizerIntent.RESULT_AUDIO_ERROR);
                        startActivityForResult(i, check);
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        if (requestCode == check && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                            result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                            searchVoiceArray();
                        }

                        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                    }

        public void searchVoiceArray() {
                int size = result.size();
                int i = 0;
                while (i < size) {
                    String s = result.get(i);
                    s.toLowerCase();
                    // next line removes all spaces in the string
                    // s= s.replaceAll(" ", "");
                    if (s.indexOf("text messaging") != -1 || s.indexOf("texts") != -1) {
                        i = size;
                        //Start text messaging intent Here
                    } 
                    else if (s.indexOf("email") != -1) {
                        i = size;
                    //Start email intent Here
                    } 
                   else
                     i++;
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
```