# Android Voice Recognition Commands

Tags: android, voice-recognition

**Goal**

Voice recognition starts, a voice command is spoken and the correct action is done. (Play Some Music starts the music player of whatever supposed to happen.)

**Current situation**

I have a test application running which start the Android Voice Recognition, successfully listens and returns a result to my Activity.

Snippet to start voice recognition:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
 intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak your mind.");
 startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Snippet for the result:

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
            // matches hold the spoken words
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

What would be the best approach for this problem?

Comment: Well.. there's a lot that can be said here depending on how far you want to go (ultimately you'll want to have some NLU engine), but what I'll do instead is forward you to a hack that is getting some attention today that you can look at the code for quick-and-dirty parsing of commands (this is NOT robust, but works for a limited set of commands/grammars): https://s3.amazonaws.com/static.echonest.com/talkradio/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is..

```
 if (matches.contains("close"))
        {
            finish();
        }
```