# how to create a speech recognition app:which listens certain voice commands n performs the action?

Tags: android, speech

how should I create such an app which listens to certain specified voice commands n then performs the respective actions? 
For example if I say Play Music it should start my music app and so on.
And this app should always be running in the background(like a service).
Is Artificial Intelligence required? If so then how to implement it?

Till now I've this code which listens to what I say an then displays it,so I was thinking if I could get the text which is being displayed in the text view and check if it matches the names of any of the other activities present and if the name matches then that activity is started.Is it possible? Also is it possible to make this work off line?

> public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

```
protected static final int REQUEST_OK = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
         i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
             try {
             startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_OK);
         } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error initializing speech to text engine.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==REQUEST_OK  && resultCode==RESULT_OK) {
                ArrayList<String> thingsYouSaid = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1)).setText(thingsYouSaid.get(0));
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Speech recognition is required. And since speech recognition appears to work as of today, it's no longer AI (tm).

Comment: ok..thnx.Can only Google API be used? Or something else too..

Comment: See the question and my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15122400/android-voice-recognition-commands/23931056#23931056